# Commenting out other comments with PHP?

Tags: php, comments

Can I comment out lines which have other comments?

```
/*
 * comment 1
 */

$var = 0;
$if();

/*
 * comment 2
 */
$var2 = 2;
```

Is there a way to comment out all these lines together?
I often have a long function or logic and would like to comment out the rest for testing.

Comment: only if you had used line comments (`#`, `//`).

Comment: I don't know if there's a function to do that with multiline comments, but I know IDE like Dreamweaver have a button to remove the comments.
So maybe you can use that, save and test.

Comment: Comment blocks cannot be nested inside other comment blocks.

Comment: imagine you would have an option for that, and then someone would want to comment that super comment block as well, and then another would want to comment that super super comment block and then... better off not allowing nesting of comments. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered skipping over the code by placing it inside an if(0) block?

For example:

```
<?php
if( 0 ) {
     print("This code is 'commented' out");


... other commented out code is here ...


}
?>
```

Comment: Good one! This is pretty much what i do now, i was just wondering if there is a proper way to just comment out everything including multiline comments

Comment: Good, probably better than my heredoc example as it will have very little overhead.

Comment: An added benefit to using this is that you can problematically turn blocks of code on and off by using a configuration like variable in the "if" statement.  For example `if( $debug )` or `if( ! $debug )`.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your best bet would be to use the comment blocks `/* */` sparingly, and use more line comments `//` or `#`.

A comment block can hide multiple lines, even if those lines have single line comments. However, a comment block cannot work with another comment block inside it.

Syntax here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

Comment: Why someone downvotes this is unknown to me. My response is specifically targeted at comments as per the question. Not using active code.

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP manual:

> > 'C' style comments end at the first */ encountered. Make sure you don't nest 'C' style comments. It is easy to make this mistake if you
> >     are trying to comment out a large block of code.
>
> ```
> <?php
>  /*
>     echo 'This is a test'; /* This comment will cause a problem */
>  */
> ?>
> ```

You might be able to do something with Heredoc syntax, such as:

```
<<<VAR    
    /*
     * comment 1
     */

    $var = 0;
    $if();

    /*
     * comment 2
     */
    $var2 = 2;
VAR;
```

Comment: This looks really interesting, have you tried out anything of this sort?

Comment: I get some errors while using this method `Undefined variable`

Comment: Heredoc? Bad idea due to variable expansion. Use Nowdoc instead: `<<<'VAR'`

Answer (score 0):

Most of code editors allow you to comment and uncomment whole blocks of code with `//`. Usually it is some combination of `Ctrl+Shift/Alt+C`. Very convinient Check your text editor's reference.